# Orthographic Camera screen on different sized phones

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx, orthographic

My Orthographic camera is initialized to be size 540x960 (the size of my HTC One screen).  However, when I try it on another phone with a larger screen, whenever I tap to move my Texture, there is an offset from where I touch and where the Texture moves to.  Should I use a different sizing technique?  Such as size it by Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and .getHeight()?

From comment below:

```
@Override         
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    xpos = x;       
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: There are several different strategies you can use for sizing your screen. A fixed aspect ratio like that is not a good one, because it will look distorted on phones that don't have the exact same ratio. But regardless of how you size your orthographic camera, you should not be having the issue you are having if you are calculating touch correctly. What method are you using to get the world space touch position?

Comment: i'm using GestureDetector.  Here's a sample of how I handle touch:

`@Override
  

public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   xpos = x;
   return false;
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting the screen's x position. To convert it to world space (the coordinate system of your game), you need to put it into a Vector3 and unproject it from the camera like this:

```
@Override         
public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3(x, y, 0); //0 is arbitrary since this is in 2D
    camera.unproject(touchPoint); //now touchPoint contains the world position of the touch
    xpos = touchPoint.x;      
    ypos = touchPoint.y; //if you need it. 
    return false;       
}
```